# Are there any Lubuntu server version?

Tags: server, lubuntu

I want to install a linux server on my old machine (running windows XP, Intel Atom CPU, 150GB HDD), but my computer cant install ubuntu server 18.04.

Lubuntu is a lite ubuntu version, but i cant see any server version at the website 'lubuntu.net/downloads/'.

Are there any server version for Lubuntu?

Comment: A properly-configured server usually does not need a GUI. I maintain all my servers remotely using plain old SSH. It's not difficult to setup or to learn.

Comment: The site you list is not a Ubuntu or Lubuntu site.  If you're unsure what are official sites, please don't ask a search engine, but go to ubuntu.com and search there (eg. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will point you to legitimate sites for each flavor).

Answer (score 5):

Lubuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu desktop.

All flavors of Ubuntu are desktops, with the default desktop replaced by another, eg.

- Xubuntu uses XFCE
- Kubuntu uses KDE
- Lubuntu used LXDE up to 18.04,
  LXQt from 18.10 up
- Ubuntu-MATE uses MATE desktop
- Ubuntu-Budgie uses
  Budgie desktop
- Ubuntu-Studio used XFCE up to 20.04, and KDE from 20.10 up
- Ubuntu-Kylin uses Kylin
  desktop

Ubuntu desktop uses Unity 7 for 16.04, and GNOME for 17.10 and later

Desktops use resources, which is seen as a waste for servers. No flavor of Ubuntu is geared for server use, though yes if you're willing to pay the cost of less efficiency (ram, cycles, thus $power) you can add desktops to your server install.

*The site you list is not a Ubuntu or Lubuntu site.  If you're unsure what are official sites, please don't ask a search engine, but go to ubuntu.com and search there (eg. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will point you to legitimate sites for each flavor)*.

Comment: There are other flavors, but some are no longer supported (eg. Ubuntu-GNOME ended when GNOME became the default desktop, edubuntu...).  GNOME was the default desktop long ago (up to 10.10 I think from memory, Unity 7 from 11.04 to 17.04 inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem and searched the difference between server version and desktop version and i found that the basic difference is the lack of GUI in the server version.

So i suggest you install Lubuntu desktop in you PC, maybe 16.x version, that only consumes 300mb of ram(very affordable in any pc) plus you would have an gui to manage the server if you need it.

Also you can use that version as server. See:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/difference-ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-server/
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/beginners-guide-setting-ssh-linux-testing-setup/

For more info.

PD: *lubuntu.net* is an unofficial site of Lubuntu. The official website is https://lubuntu.me

PD2: corrected official ste and unofficial site(they were switched)

Comment: I edited your question to make the unofficial site un-clickable, and please note all flavors of 16.04 are now EOL except for Kylin.  Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7), or Kylin have 5 years of supported life and are still supported, all other 16.x are EOL.